# Why does "Baby Daddy" TV series have a very difficult accent?

Tags: speech, accent, fast-speech-rules

I can hardly understand  [*Baby Daddy* TV series season 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2177489/), so I downloaded the script. Now, I can recognize words and sentences because I read along as I listen. But I still find it a very fast accent. I watch many English videos on YouTube such as TED talks and they are not that fast. Why is there a difference? Does *Baby Daddy* have a special accent?

As a native speaker, what do you use in your daily life, and what is the accent spoken in the American street? Is it as fast as *Baby Daddy*?

Comment: People doing formal presentations, such as TED talks, make a *conscious* effort to not only slow down their speech but enunciate very clearly - sometimes exaggeratedly. If you were to talk to your buddies in the bar at the same speed, they'd think something was wrong with you. I'm a salesman and I do presentations to customers constantly, and I'll tell you one of the hardest things being aware of and maintaining a slow pace.

Comment: FWIW, after flipping through a few clips just now, the main cast all speak with something close to *General American*— i.e. neutral American English without any regional accent. Speech rate is more complicated; for example, people may pronounce syllables quickly, but take longer pauses between words. But it doesn't strike me (native speaker, urban bicoastal) as unusually fast. [This blog](http://sixminutes.dlugan.com/speaking-rate/) says Steve Jobs' TED talk averages 158 syllables per minute, while various sources say Americans on average converse anywhere from to 160-190 wpm.